# allowing a user to access adminpanel?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I created a form to register users. I need the user to have access after registration adminpanel. for this I have tried to override the value of the field is_staff:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):   
    is_staff = forms.CharField(
        default=True,
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
    )   

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (  
            'username',   
            'email',    
            'password1', 
            'password2',
            'is_staff',
        )
```

views:

```
def registration(request):
    """
    ajax refistration procedure
    """ 
    result = False      

    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)   
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                new_user = form.save()
            except:
                pass
            else:
                result = True

    data = {
        'result': result,       
    }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

the problem is that the browser displays the following error message:

```
TypeError at /
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default' Request Method: GET Request URL:     Django Version:    1.6.8
Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value:  
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default' Exception Location: /home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py
in __init__, line 198
```

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with allowing users access to the admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting means the keyword argument `default=True` is incorrect when creating the `is_staff` field.

You should be using `initial=True` instead [to specify an initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial).

Furthermore, you are using a `forms.CharField` for the `is_staff` field, which presumably should be a boolean (so `forms.BooleanField`). After that it'll be displayed as a tick box and not as a field for text characters.